# Scheduling problem. Get most workers pe shift based on times available.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to fill a work schedule with three shifts.

Lets say I have a list of people. Each person tells me A) Which of the three shifts they are available to work, and B) How many shifts they can work.

So for example, Person 1 might say they can work shift 2 and 3, and would only like to work 1 of those. Person 2 might say they can work shift 1,2, or 3, and would like to work 2 shifts.

People working multiple shifts must work in consecutive ones (i.e. a person can not work shift 1 and 3).

How can I come up with a schedule from this information that maximizes the number of people working per shift?

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of people you want to work a shift, or do you accept all comers?

Comment: A second question.  To what extent are the employees' requests honored?  If a person says he's available to work 2 shifts but only wants to work one, does that mean he will never be assigned to two shifts?  If a person is available for three shifts but would like to work two, is it possible that he will be assigned to only one shift?

Comment: No limit on people per shift, the more the better.

And the number of shifts an employee works must be less than or equal to the number they requested.

Comment: But there must be some other constraint you're trying to satisfy; otherwise you can just give everybody all the shifts he's willing to work.  In fact, from what you've said so far, it seems like you would never give anyone fewer shifts than he's willing to work.  Don't you have a minimum number that must work each shift?

Comment: I think the ambiguity comes in when trying do decide which shift(s) to place people on that can work any of the 3 shifts, but only want to work one or two.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but it won't fit in a comment.

Unless you have some other goals, it seems like the problem is trivial.

1. If a person has only one schedule he's willing to work, give him that schedule.
2. If he's willing to work on more than one shift but wants to work only one shift, give him the earliest shift he's willing to work.
3. If he wants to work two shifts, but is willing to work any of the three shifts, put him on the first two shifts.

Now, this satisfies all the criteria you've enunciated, but I can't help feeling that it wouldn't be a satisfactory solution, since it favors the earlier shifts over the later shifts.  If there are other criteria that you need to satisfy, please put them into the body of the question.

So far, the problem sounds like it can be formulated as a linear programming problem with $0-1$ variables.  Suppose there are $n$ employees.  We have $3n$ variables $x_{ij} \text{ where } 1\le i \le n, 1 \le j \le 3,$ all taking values in $\{0,1\}.$  The interpretation is that $x_{ij}=1$ if employee $i$ is assigned to shift $j,$ and $0$ otherwise.

Now, you want to maximize the sum of all the $x_{ij}$ subject to certain conditions.  For example, if employee $i$ is willing to work shift $1$ or $3$, but not shift $2$, that would be represented as $x_{i1}+x_{i3}=1.$  If employee $i$ wants to work two shifts, and is willing to work on any shift, we have two conditions: $x_{i1}+x_{i2}+x_{i3}=2,$ and $x_{i1}+x_{i3}=1.$

If it weren't for the requirement that no one work shifts $1$ and $3,$ it seems to me that this could be modeled as an instance of network flow, with minimum and maximum capacities on the edges. That would probably be more efficient to solve than a linear programming problem.  I don't see how to accommodate the rule, though.

This is sort of an operations research problem.  I looked, but there isn't a Stack Exchange site for operations research.  You might have good luck on the [Computer Science site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), though, because network flow is an important problem in computing.